# Unity 2D animations

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, break, continue

I am developing an platformer and recently i`ve faced with such a irritating problem.

I made an attack animation from the idle animation for the player. Seems not so difficult, isn't it? But then I wanted to make another one, but this time from the run animation. The robot(the main character) always keeps a wrench in his hand and this hand is animated while playing run animation. So I want to break a run animation, play attack and then return to the run animation in a certain time. Are there any functions in unity to make this?

Just **break** and **continue** but for unity animation...

Answer (score 1):

Please, learn about [unity`s animation system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationOverview.html). There are a lot of video tutorials for basics things you asked.

In short, you have to use Animator Controller component, which have a state-machine inside for your animations. You can control this state-machine, setting parameters. So, to do what you want, you just need to set some defined trigger for attack, and then, when you need, set another trigger for run animation.

Comment: Yes, I know, but can I make such operations as break and continue there?

Comment: What exactly you want to do? Character runs. You want to play attack, then return to run? Do you mean how to interrupt current run animation? Or you need to play attack animation only for robot's hand? Or you need to return to exactly that animation time of running, where you are switched to attack?

Comment: The third: I want to interrupt hand's animation of running, play attack with this hand and then return to specific moment in running animation of hand. I guess there is another more easy way to do attack animation but I am sure I am don't experienced enough in unity.

Comment: There are different animation layers in unity. You can put attack animation on separate layer. You can set an avatar mask for layer - the set of transforms, which will be affected by this layer, in your case it`s hand transforms. Also there is a layer weight. And two blend modes: additive and override, you need to set override.

Comment: So, you create an "attack" layer, which holds a hand animation. This layer has an avatar mask, which excludes from animation everything, except hand. Initial layer weight is 0. When you need attack animation, you set layer weight to 1, and start to play attack animation. Robot's legs still running - they controlled by running animation on base layer. But his hand does hit. After that (you need to know timing), you set layer weight back to zero, and robot continues to run, as usual.

Comment: Oh, it really worked nice, thanks a lot!!!!!! Before this thread I haven't even heard anything about animation layers.